# How to add layer to control box

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have kml layers that i can add to embedded google map, but those layers aren't added into the top right control box which allows me to show/hide the layers in the map.

How can i add them into that control box ?
I can show/hide the layer using js but its not native google maps look and feel.

Also, i have noticed that i can see only Map/Satellite/labels options in the control box, not all regular layers that appear in the [maps.google.com][1] maps, why is that ?

My code looks like that:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: center,
        draggable: true,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: '<?php echo $map_type ?>',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
      });

var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map
      });

kmlLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: What does your code/page look like?

Comment: Just added code to the question